# Otimizar gráfico highchart

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts, gráfico

Pediram que eu acrescentasse no meu sistema um gráfico pra comparar 47 serviços e optei pelo highchart, porém, além do gráfico não funcionar está com mais de 5.000 linhas de código, preciso reduzir isso urgente mas como não domino a linguagem não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.

A ideia do gráfico é bem simples, ele só pega a quantidade de registros de cada um dos 47 serviços por mês, ou seja, eu fiz 47 selects 12 vezes.

Esse é o famoso gráfico:

```
 /*-------------------------------------Janeiro ---------------------------------*/
        require_once("strcon.php");
        $totaSAJ = 0;
        $totaSBJ = 0;
        $totaSCJ = 0;
        $totaSDJ = 0;
        $totaSEJ = 0;
        $totaSFJ = 0;
        $totaSGJ = 0;
        $totaSHJ = 0;
        $totaSIJ = 0;
        $totaSJJ = 0;
        $totaSKJ = 0;
        $totaSLJ = 0;
        $totaSMJ = 0;
        $totaSNJ = 0;
        $totaSOJ = 0;
        $totaSPJ = 0;
        $totaSQJ = 0;
        $totaSRJ = 0;
        $totaSSJ = 0;
        $totaSTJ = 0;
        $totaSUJ = 0;
        $totaSVJ = 0;
        $totaSXJ = 0;
        $totaSZJ = 0;
        $totaSAAJ = 0;
        $totaSABJ = 0;
        $totaSACJ = 0;
        $totaSADJ = 0;
        $totaSAEJ = 0;
        $totaSAFJ = 0;
        $totaSAGJ = 0;
        $totaSAHJ = 0;
        $totaSAIJ = 0;
        $totaSAJJ = 0;
        $totaSAKJ = 0;
        $totaSALJ = 0;
        $totaSAMJ = 0;
        $totaSANJ = 0;
        $totaSAOJ = 0;
        $totaSAPJ = 0;
        $totaSAQJ = 0;
        $totaSARJ = 0;
        $totaSASJ = 0;
        $totaSATJ = 0;
        $totaSAUJ = 0;

        $SAJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Quadri Hélix' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SBJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SBJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Quadri Hélix com grade' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SCJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SCJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Quadri Hélix com batente' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SDJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SDJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Botão de Nance' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SEJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SEJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Botão Barra' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SFJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SFJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Barra Transplatina' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SGJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SGJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Barra Transplatina com grade' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SHJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SHJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Arco Lingual' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SIJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SIJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Mantedor de espaço (Alça Banda)' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SJJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SJJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Contenção Fixa Higiência' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SKJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SKJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Contenção Fixa V Bend' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SLJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SLJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Disjuntor de Mc Namara' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SMJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SMJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Disjuntor Mc Namara com grade' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SNJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SNJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Disjuntor Mc Namara modificado' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SOJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SOJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Disjuntor de Haas' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SPJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SPJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Disjuntor de Hirax' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SQJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SQJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Grade Lingual ou Palatina' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SRJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SRJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Platô' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SSJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SSJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Contenção com arco de Hawley' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $STJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS STJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Contenção com arco de Hawley continuo' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SUJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SUJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Contenção com arco estático' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SVJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SVJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Ap. de Hawley com Expansor' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SXJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SXJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Ap. de Hawley Encapsulado com Expansor e Aleta' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SZJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SZJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Ap. de Hawley Encapsulado com Expansor e Grade' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SAAJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAAJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Ap. de Hawley com grade' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SABJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SABJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Ap. de Hawley com Grade e Expansor' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SACJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SACJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Ap. de Hawley com Reeducador para Língua' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SADJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SADJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Ap. de Hawley com Expansor e molas' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $AEJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAEJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Ap. de Hawley com Batente' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SAFJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAFJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Ap. de Hawley com Batente e Expansor' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SAGJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAGJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Ap. de Hawley com Expansor e Trava (Central ou Aleta)' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SAHJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAHJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Ap. de Thurow' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SAIJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAIJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Ap. de Thurow com Expansor' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SAJJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAJJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Ap. de Bruxismo (Mio Relaxante)' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SAKJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAKJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Placa de Michigan' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SALJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SALJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Ap. de Acetato' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SAMJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAMJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Placa de Clareamento (par)' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SANJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SANJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Dentes de Estoque (unidade)' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SAOJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAOJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Monobloco' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SAPJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAPJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Planas' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SAQJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAQJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Bimbler' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SARJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SARJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Bíator' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SASJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SASJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Klammt' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SATJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SATJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Equilibradora / SNs' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SAUJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAUJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Frankel' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";
        $SAVJ = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAVJan FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Ronco e Apnéia' and MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018'";

        $consultasaj = mysqli_query($SAJ);
        $consultasbj = mysqli_query($SBJ);
        $consultascj = mysqli_query($SCJ);
        $consultasdj = mysqli_query($SDJ);
        $consultasej = mysqli_query($SEJ);
        $consultasfj = mysqli_query($SFJ);
        $consultasgj = mysqli_query($SGJ);
        $consultashj = mysqli_query($SHJ);
        $consultasij = mysqli_query($SIJ);
        $consultasjj = mysqli_query($SJJ);
        $consultaskj = mysqli_query($SKJ);
        $consultaslj = mysqli_query($SLJ);
        $consultasmj = mysqli_query($SMJ);
        $consultasnj = mysqli_query($SNJ);
        $consultasoj = mysqli_query($SOJ);
        $consultaspj = mysqli_query($SPJ);
        $consultasqj = mysqli_query($SQJ);
        $consultasrj = mysqli_query($SRJ);
        $consultassj = mysqli_query($SSJ);
        $consultastj = mysqli_query($STJ);
        $consultasuj = mysqli_query($SUJ);
        $consultasvj = mysqli_query($SVJ);
        $consultasxj = mysqli_query($SXJ);
        $consultaszj = mysqli_query($SZJ);
        $consultasaaj = mysqli_query($SAAJ);
        $consultasabj = mysqli_query($SABJ);
        $consultasacj = mysqli_query($SACJ);
        $consultasadj = mysqli_query($SADJ);
        $consultasaej = mysqli_query($SAEJ);
        $consultasafj = mysqli_query($SAFJ);
        $consultasagj = mysqli_query($SAGJ);
        $consultasahj = mysqli_query($SAHJ);
        $consultasaij = mysqli_query($SAIJ);
        $consultasajj = mysqli_query($SAJJ);
        $consultasakj = mysqli_query($SAKJ);
        $consultasalj = mysqli_query($SALJ);
        $consultasamj = mysqli_query($SAMJ);
        $consultasanj = mysqli_query($SANJ);
        $consultasaoj = mysqli_query($SAOJ);
        $consultasapj = mysqli_query($SAPJ);
        $consultasaqj = mysqli_query($SAQJ);
        $consultasarj = mysqli_query($SARJ);
        $consultasasj = mysqli_query($SASJ);
        $consultasatj = mysqli_query($SATJ);
        $consultasauj = mysqli_query($SAUJ);
        $consultasavj = mysqli_query($SAVJ);

        if ($consultasaj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAJ)) {
            if ($rowsaj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasaj)) {
                $totaSAJ = $rowsaj['SAJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasaj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasbj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SBJ)) {
            if ($rowsbj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasbj)) {
                $totaSBJ = $rowsbj['SBJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasbj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultascj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SCJ)) {
            if ($rowscj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultascj)) {
                $totaSCJ = $rowsbj['SCJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultascj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasdj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SDJ)) {
            if ($rowsdj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasdj)) {
                $totaSDJ = $rowsbj['SDJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasdj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasej = mysqli_query($strcon, $SEJ)) {
            if ($rowsej = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasej)) {
                $totaSEJ = $rowsbj['SEJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasej);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasfj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SFJ)) {
            if ($rowsfj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasfj)) {
                $totaSFJ = $rowsfj['SFJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasfj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasgj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SGJ)) {
            if ($rowsgj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasgj)) {
                $totaSGJ = $rowsgj['SGJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasgj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultashj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SHJ)) {
            if ($rowshj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultashj)) {
                $totaSHJ = $rowshj['SHJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultashj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasij = mysqli_query($strcon, $SIJ)) {
            if ($rowsij = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasij)) {
                $totaSIJ = $rowsij['SIJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasij);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasjj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SJJ)) {
            if ($rowsjj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasjj)) {
                $totaSJJ = $rowsjj['SJJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasjj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultaskj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SKJ)) {
            if ($rowskj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultaskj)) {
                $totaSKJ = $rowskj['SKJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultaskj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultaslj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SLJ)) {
            if ($rowslj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultaslj)) {
                $totaSLJ = $rowslj['SLJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultaslj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasmj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SCMJ)) {
            if ($rowsmj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasmj)) {
                $totaSMJ = $rowsmj['SMJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasmj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasnj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SNJ)) {
            if ($rowsnj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasnj)) {
                $totaSNJ = $rowsnj['SNJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasnj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasoj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SOJ)) {
            if ($rowseoj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasoj)) {
                $totaSOJ = $rowsoj['SOJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasoj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultaspj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SPJ)) {
            if ($rowspj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultaspj)) {
                $totaSPJ = $rowspj['SPJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultaspj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasqj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SQJ)) {
            if ($rowsqj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasqj)) {
                $totaSQJ = $rowsqj['SQJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasqj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasrj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SRJ)) {
            if ($rowsrj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasrj)) {
                $totaSRJ = $rowsrj['SRJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasrj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultassj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SSJ)) {
            if ($rowssj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultassj)) {
                $totaSSJ = $rowssj['SSJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultassj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultastj = mysqli_query($strcon, $STJ)) {
            if ($rowstj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultastj)) {
                $totaSTJ = $rowstj['STJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultastj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasuj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SUJ)) {
            if ($rowsuj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasuj)) {
                $totaSUJ = $rowsuj['SUJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasuj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasvj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SVJ)) {
            if ($rowsvj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasvj)) {
                $totaSVJ = $rowsvj['SVJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasvj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasxj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SXJ)) {
            if ($rowsxj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasxj)) {
                $totaSXJ = $rowsxj['SXJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasxj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultaszj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SZJ)) {
            if ($rowszj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultaszj)) {
                $totaSZJ = $rowszj['SZJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultaszj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasaaj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAAJ)) {
            if ($rowsaaj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasaaj)) {
                $totaSAAJ = $rowsaaj['SAAJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasaaj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasabj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SABJ)) {
            if ($rowsabj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasabj)) {
                $totaSABJ = $rowsabj['SABJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasabj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasacj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SACJ)) {
            if ($rowsacj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasacj)) {
                $totaSACJ = $rowsacj['SACJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasacj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasadj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SADJ)) {
            if ($rowsadj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasadj)) {
                $totaSADJ = $rowsadj['SADJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasadj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasaej = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAEJ)) {
            if ($rowsaej = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasaej)) {
                $totaSAEJ = $rowsaej['SAEJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasaej);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasafj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAFJ)) {
            if ($rowsafj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasafj)) {
                $totaSAFJ = $rowsafj['SAFJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasafj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasagj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAGJ)) {
            if ($rowsagj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasagj)) {
                $totaSAGJ = $rowsagj['SAGJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasagj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasahj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAHJ)) {
            if ($rowsahj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasahj)) {
                $totaSAHJ = $rowsahj['SAHJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasahj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasaij = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAIJ)) {
            if ($rowsaij = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasaij)) {
                $totaSAIJ = $rowsaij['SAIJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasaij);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasajj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAJJ)) {
            if ($rowsajj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasajj)) {
                $totaSAJJ = $rowsajj['SAJJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasajj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultaskj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAKJ)) {
            if ($rowsakj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasakj)) {
                $totaSAKJ = $rowsakj['SAKJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasakj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasalj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SALJ)) {
            if ($rowsalj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasalj)) {
                $totaSALJ = $rowsalj['SALJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasalj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasamj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAMJ)) {
            if ($rowsamj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasamj)) {
                $totaSAMJ = $rowsamj['SAMJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasamj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasanj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SANJ)) {
            if ($rowsanj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasanj)) {
                $totaSANJ = $rowsanj['SANJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasanj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasaoj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAOJ)) {
            if ($rowsaoj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasaoj)) {
                $totaSAOJ = $rowsaoj['SAOJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasaoj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasapj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAPJ)) {
            if ($rowsapj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasapj)) {
                $totaSAPJ = $rowsapj['SAPJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasapj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasapj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAPJ)) {
            if ($rowsapj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasapj)) {
                $totaSAJ = $rowsaj['SAJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasapj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasaqj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAQJ)) {
            if ($rowsaqj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasaqj)) {
                $totaSAQJ = $rowsaqj['SAQJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasaqj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasarj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SARJ)) {
            if ($rowsarj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasarj)) {
                $totaSARJ = $rowsarj['SARJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasarj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasasj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SASJ)) {
            if ($rowsasj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasasj)) {
                $totaSASJ = $rowsasj['SASJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasasj);
        } else {

        }
        if ($consultasatj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SATJ)) {
            if ($rowsatj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasatj)) {
                $totaSATJ = $rowsatj['SATJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasatj);
        } else {

        }

        if ($consultasavj = mysqli_query($strcon, $SAVJ)) {
            if ($rowsavj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consultasavj)) {
                $totaSAVJ = $rowsavj['SAVJan']; //Seta o total
            }
            mysqli_free_result($consultasavj);
        } else {

        }



?>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        Highcharts.chart('container', {

            title: {
                text: 'Indicador anual de serviços'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: [{
                categories: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
                crosshair: true
            }],

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
            },


        series: [{
        name: 'Quadri Hélix',
        data: [<?php echo $rowsaj['SAJan'];?>, <?php echo $rowsaf['SAFev'];?>,<?php echo $rowsamar['SAMar'];?>, <?php echo $rowsaabr['SAAbr'];?>, <?php echo $rowsamai['SAMai'];?>, <?php echo $rowsajun['SAJun'];?>, <?php echo $rowsajul['SAJul'];?>, <?php echo $rowsaago['SAAgo'];?>, <?php echo $rowsaset['SASet'];?>, <?php echo $rowsaout['SAOut'];?>, <?php echo $rowsanov['SANov'];?>, <?php echo $rowsadez['SADez'];?>]
    }, {
        name: 'Quadri Hélix com grade',
        data: [<?php echo $rowsbj['SBJan'];?>,<?php echo $rowsbf['SBFev'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbmar['SBMar'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbabr['SBAbr'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbmai['SBMai'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbjun['SBJun'];?>,<?php echo $rowsbjul['SBJul'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbago['SBAgo'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbset['SBSet'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbout['SBOut'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbnov['SBNov'];?>, <?php echo $rowsbdez['SBDez'];?>]
    }, {

            responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                        tickInterval: 1,
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        legend: {
                            layout: 'horizontal',
                            align: 'center',
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }

        });
        </script>
```

Não consegui colocar o código inteiro aqui mas nem tem necessidade, a parte em php só repete a mesma coisa que eu fiz pra janeiro em todos os meses. A parte em jscript só repete a mesma coisa que eu fiz nos dois serviços pra todos os 47 serviços.

Segue imagens do famoso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Alguém sabe como otimizar, reduzir o tamanho desse negócio?

Comment: Por que não faz uma sql somente? Ex: `SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAVJan, SERVICO FROM pedidos WHERE MES = 'JAN' and ANO = '2018' GROUP BY SERVICO`? Já reduz a metade do código... E vc vai ter um array com a qtde e nome do serviço, ai é só colocar no chart.

Comment: Ué, não entendi. Esse select vai me retornar a quantidade de registros de todos os serviços? E como eu coloco desse jeito no highchart se eu coloco cada select sendo um valor no mês?

Comment: `series: [{
                name: 'Quadri Hélix',
                data: [<?php echo $rowsaj['SAJan'];?>, <?php echo $rowsaf['SAFev'];?>,<?php echo $rowsamar['SAMar'];?>, <?php echo $rowsaabr['SAAbr'];?>, <?php echo $rowsamai['SAMai'];?>, <?php echo $rowsajun['SAJun'];?>, <?php echo $rowsajul['SAJul'];?>, <?php echo $rowsaago['SAAgo'];?>, <?php echo $rowsaset['SASet'];?>, <?php echo $rowsaout['SAOut'];?>, <?php echo $rowsanov['SANov'];?>, <?php echo $rowsadez['SADez'];?>]` --> Aqui ele vai pegar o primeiro serviço de cada mês pra montar a linha do primeiro serviço. Preciso de todos os select

Comment: Eu não entendi no seu código aonde você busca os meses, sendo que na consulta do banco você tem apenas a condição `WHERE MES = 'JAN'`

Comment: Pra cada mês eu fiz 47 selects `SELECT COUNT(ID) AS SAMar FROM pedidos WHERE SERVICO = 'Serviço A' and MES = 'MAR' and ANO = '2018'"` Depois eu pego a quantidade de registros apresentados em cada select, coloco numa row e coloco a row no highchart.